# Access-Control-Allow-Origin requests with web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

We have an intranet application we are working on with an AngularJS front end and a Web Api back end. It's basically a redesign of an existing ASP.NET/WCF app and it's only used by a few of our employees.

We had intended to enforce some security in this version (the old one had none) using Windows Authentication and we've had some problems getting that to work with browsers other than Internet Explorer. Chrome, for example always comes back with a 401-Unauthorized error.

I've been instructed to skip the security features for now (yeah I know, not a good idea) so I've disabled them but now I'm seeing an error when I attempt to talk to the API (in a separate project), but in Chrome and not in IE.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:62415/api/Emails. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50900' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

We've enabled CORS in our API project so I am not sure what I need to do here.  We are using localhost in our local development but in QA and production these sites will be using URLs with different subdomains within the same domain.

I am using a Startup class in my project and it has this method:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

I must be missing something. We originally had this code in our WebApiConfig but restoring it didn't fix anything:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");

cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use ASP.net enough to say but what you had should do it, some other alternatives here http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html You should see a request with the method set to OPTION that goes out before the real GET/POST in the response to that request the headers should specify that the Access Control Allow Origins is set to * or whatever your actual client domain is.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to add:

> var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
>   config.EnableCors(cors);

For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. 
For example, XMLHttpRequest follows the same-origin policy. So, a web application using XMLHttpRequest could only make HTTP requests to its own domain.
**However, You can pass that by:**

> - install Microsoft.Owin.Cors package in nuget
> - add this method in Startup.cs

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        }
```